# How long do C# reference types live inside a method?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I can't find a clear answer for this. If I instantiate a reference type inside a method but do not store it on any class variable, how long does this reference live on the heap? Is it marked as garbage on the method return and eventually get cleared by the Garbage collector?

```
void DoSomeStuff()
{
   var myRefInstance = new Object();
}
```

Comment: "Is it marked as garbage on the method return and eventually get cleared by the Garbage collector?" Yeap. However the process is un-determinstic, you can´t **really** say when an instance is collected. All you can do is to indicate when it is **eligable** for collection. For further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

Comment: It can be marked as garbage even before the method returns. It's marked as garbage whenever the garbage collector determines that the reference is no longer used.

Comment: Note that an object might be collected *before* it goes out of scope. The runtime knows when a variable isn't going to be used again, it doesn't really care about its scope. `GC.KeepAlive` exists for this reason.

Comment: GC really is one of those things that people focus on far too much at times. The whole point of the system is to let people not have to think about timing, memory management, etc and then people obsess over precisely those matters. If timing matters at all, you're probably looking for `IDisposable`, not GC.

Comment: In my case its mainly out of curiosity and the joy of increasing my knowledge :) not really because of performance or design requirements in this case, but I still think its useful information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects that are not reachable are marked as collectable. When the object is collected depends on the GC; if there is no memory pressure it might never be collected until the application ends.

Its important to note that the rule is "Object is not reachable", not that there is no references pointing at it, which is not the same:

```
void Foo() {
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();
    a.b = b;
    b.a = a; }
```

Both `a` and `b` will be marked as unreachable when `Foo` exits even though both would have a reference counter greater than 0.

Comment: just a clarification for the reader: it is the GC itself that marks things (notionally) as collectable / not, so when that part happens is also: dependent on the GC's whimsy

Comment: @MarcGravell in fact, in most environments, unreachable objects are never marked at all. Instead, the reachable objects are marked and saved when memory is reclaimed. The garbage is never touched.